# How do I fix a GET parameter error in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, view, get

The user selects a slot via a checkbox and also should enter a username, as shown in the template below:

```
<form action="/clubs/{{ club.id }}/vote/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for slot in tom_open_slots %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="slot" id="slot{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ slot.id }}" />
    <label for="slot{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ slot.slot }} on Court {{slot.court}}</label><br />
{% endfor %}    
<input type="text" name="username" />
<input type="submit" value="Reserve" />
```

I then would like to display the username that was typed and time selected in the checkbox.  I do this through the view and template below:

```
def vote(request, club_id):
    if 'username' in request.GET and request.GET['username'] and 'slot' in request.GET and request.GET['slot']:
        username = request.GET['username']
        slot = request.GET['slot']
        return render_to_response('reserve/templates/vote.html',{'username':username, 'slot':slot})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please enter a username and select a time.')


{{slot}}
{{username}}
```

When I go to vote.html though, I always get the error message though (Please enter a username and select a time).  What is incorrect in the view that is not picking up the 2 GET parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `POST` request in your form:

```
<form action="/clubs/{{ club.id }}/vote/" method="post">
```

But in the view, you are checking the `GET` object which comes from `GET` request:

```
request.GET
```

Change your form method to `method="get"` to fix the problem.

Edit: read more on `GET` vs `POST` request here: [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)

Answer (score 1):

In Django, the HttpRequest object has three dictionaries which give you the request parameters:

- `request.GET` gives you the query string parameters,
- `request.POST` gives you the post data, and
- `request.REQUEST` gives you both.

In your case, since the form is using the `POST` method, you should use either `request.POST` or `request.REQUEST`.

FYI: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET